# Idelic/Hom representation of locally free class groups

Tags: nt.number-theory, order-theory

Let $K$ be a number field with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ and let $G$ be a finite abelian group. Elements in $KG$ may be regarded as maps on the character group $\widehat{G}$ of $G$ via

$$\sum_{s\in G} \gamma_s s^{-1}\mapsto\left(\chi\mapsto \sum_{s\in G} \gamma_s \chi(s)^{-1}\right),$$

and this induces an isomorphism

$$ KG \simeq \prod_{\psi} K(\psi)$$

of algebras. Here $\psi$ ranges over a set of representatives of $\widehat{G}$ under the action of the absolute Galois group of $K$, and $K(\psi)$ is the field $K$ ajoint with $\psi(s)$ for $s\in G$.

Let $M$ denote the maximal $\mathcal{O}_K$-order in $KG$. Then

$$ M \simeq \prod_{\psi} \mathcal{O}(\psi), $$

where $\mathcal{O}(\psi)$ is the ring of integers in $K(\psi)$, and so its locally free class group

$$(*)\hspace{1em}\mbox{Cl}(M) \simeq \prod_{\psi}\mbox{Cl}(\mathcal{O}(\psi)).$$

Now, we have an idelic description for $\mbox{Cl}(M)$ given by

$$\mbox{Cl}(M)\simeq \frac{J(KG)}{(KG)^\times U(M)},$$

where $J(KG)$ is the restricted direct product of $(K_vG)^\times$ with respect  $(\mathcal{O}_{K_v}G)^\times$ as $v$ ranges over the (finite) primes in $K$, and $U(M) = \prod_v M_v^\times$. Regarding elements in $K_vG$ as maps on $\widehat{G}$, elements in $M_v$ are precisely whose images are algebraic units. There is a similar description for $\mbox{Cl}(\mathcal{O}(\psi))$ for each $\psi$.

**Question:** How does one describe the isomorphism $(*)$ in terms of these idelic/Hom-descriptions of the class groups?

If $K$ contains all $\exp(G)$th roots of unity, then this is easy. We can just map $(K_vG)^\times$ to $K_v^\times$ componentwise for each $v$. But otherwise, there are more primes involved idelic description of $\mbox{Cl}(\mathcal{O}_K)$ (one needs to range over all primes in $K(\psi)$). How does one take this into account?